# How to set agruments using beanshell processor in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Request parameters in http request are
username abc
password xyz
GoaheadAndlogin Login
Without hardcoding these values how to set agruments directly through beanshell code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sampler.addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method as

```
sampler.addArgument("username", "abc");
sampler.addArgument("password", "xyz");
```

moreover, you can use variables:

```
sampler.addArgument("username", vars.get("username"));
```

or properties:

```
sampler.addArgument("password", props.get("password"));
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for advanced information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.